# HtmlAgility check if subclass with specific name exists

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
<li class="sn-g">
     <span class="num">1</span>
     <span class="sym_first">
          <a class="icon>&nbsp;</a>
     </span>
     <span class="def">...text</span>
</li>
```

My HTML page contains such sub classes. However, the `sym_first` class is not present always. Using HTMLAgility I want to find whether `sym_first` class exists in the webpage. If it exists I want to get the InnerText from `def` class.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='" + sng + "']"))
{
   //How do I write this block?
   if(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='" + symfirst + "']").Contains(xxx)
   {
      //get inner text
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `SelectSingleNode()` and check if the return value is not `null` :

```
if(doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='sym_first']") != null)
{
    //get inner text
}
```

or if you mean to check `sym_first` class within current `li` (assuming that you're looping through `li` in the code snippet in question) :

```
if(node.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='sym_first']") != null)
{
    //get inner text
}
```

**UPDATE :**

In response to the error reported in the comment below, try to check if `def` class exists as well :

```
var sym_first = node.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='sym_first']");
var def = node.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='def']");
if(sym_first != null && def != null)
{
    //get inner text
}
```

Depending on the requirements, you may want to iterate only through `li` elements that have these specific content in the first place :

```
var query = "//li[@class='sn-g'][span[@class='sym_first'] and span[@class='def']]";
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(query))
{
   //get inner text
}
```

Comment: I tried now my final code looks like this

`foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='" + sng + "']"))
                    {
                    if (node.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='"+ symfirst +"']") != null)
                    {
                        definition = node.SelectSingleNode("span[@class='" + def + "']").InnerText;
                        Console.WriteLine(definition);
                    }`

However it returns the exception `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @VarDOS next time, never post codes in comment again, except if it is very short. Edit your question to include the latest codes instead.